# ASP.NET membership using created UserId in query string

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-membership

Hi I am currently learning .net and am building my first real website using .net.

I was just wondering if people considered it ok to use the generated membership UserId in the query string? and also to use this as a foreign key in a database to link relevant information to this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need it in a querystring? It is provided by...

```
If HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
    Dim user As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()
    Dim guid as Guid= DirectCast(user.ProviderUserKey, Guid)
End If
```

I wouldn't display such sensitive data users even if this wouldn't cause security issues, but simply because an application looks unsafe if everybody can see more than he needs to see. You could store it temporarily in the Session to pass it from page 1 to page2.

If you want to save the UserID as foreignkey its possible to use the uniqueid provided by the MembershipProvider.

If you want to use an integer instead(readability, less disk space), you have to create a table(`aspnet_UserID`) that maps the guid to your int-ID in a one-to-one relationship. Create also a trigger for inserts and deletes on the `aspnet_Users`-table, for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgCreateUserID] ON [dbo].[aspnet_Users]
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO dbo.aspnet_UserId(fiUser)
    SELECT UserID FROM inserted
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trDeleteUserID] ON [dbo].[aspnet_Users]
FOR DELETE
AS

DELETE FROM dbo.aspnet_UserId 
    WHERE fiUser IN(SELECT UserID FROM DELETED)
```

Comment: well i have users and admin users. admin users need to login to add information to the database that is linked to a normal user, hence it is not the current users id i require but that of another user to enable them to link and inserted data to the normal user.....if that makes any sense. I do already have it working, i was just wondering if it is all ok security wise, but i guess it should be as it is in a locked off admin section. Thanks J.

Comment: @JBoom: i still don't understand why you have to use a querystring. If page 2 needs the UserID of page 1 that an admin has selected, you could also use the Session as temporary storage. `Membership.GetUser` has also an overloaded version that takes the username, so you can not only get the user that is currently logged in but any user.

Comment: i think coming from classic asp i'm not fully aware of whats available to use as yet. but the issue is that a admin user would select a user from a list, but to POST the userid would mean each users info would need a FORM around it, but as the page can only have 1 FORM tag i thought it would be best just to GET the selected user to the user details page (hope that makes sense?!).

Comment: @JBoom: yes, makes sense. But again, you could also use the Session to store the selected user temporarily: `Session("SelectedUsername") = userNameFromList` and in details-page: `Dim user As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(Session("SelectedUsername").ToString)`. Clear this session-variable then: `Session("SelectedUsername") = Nothing`

Comment: But don't i still need to pass the selected UserId to the details page before i store in a session? and the only way i know i can do this from this page is by  querystring, is there another way?

Comment: @JBoom: you can store it in the Session in the Codebehind of page 1(where admin selects an user)f.e. in the click-handler of the `ShowDetails`-Button. Then you don't have to pass a value because Session is server-memory and accessible from everywhere in the application. Session-variables are limited to the user that stores them. So if two admins would parallel select users and go to the detail-page, they would have different `Session("SelectedUsername")`-values.

Comment: ah yes, of course i can, sorry probably still got my classic asp trail of thought. I will change my code to reflect this so i no longer show the UserId, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

surely is good to link user related data to the user with FK, depending on the design of your database.

in general I would not put user id in the querystring unless really required, if you have enabled and you support user authentication properly, the information of the currently connected user is available in the User.Identity and Principal classes.

Comment: hi, the problem being that i'm not after the current users UserId.

Answer (score 0):

Good security through obscurity principles dictate id's should not be included in the query string.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

But then **IF** you have a properly secured application, id's should be fine.

You should probably be storing the UserId in the session anyway, so it is not transmitted to the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I understand all that and have tried to implement where possible. The only place the userid's are in the querystring is in a locked off admin section so i think it should all be ok. Thanks again J.